# How can I wait for a thread to finish running other than by calling thread.Join()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-3.0

I am working on a project where the methods are called from the an application which is available with the library.

I have the below code in my button click event:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AddPics));
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
thread.Start();
execute();
```

But while running the sample always the execution point moves to the execute. How to make the program to execute the `AddPics` method first. I have tried `thread.Join()` and it worked, but I want to know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: If you're going to pause until the thread's completed, why not just call `AddPics` directly - why use threads at all?

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want to use the Thread.Join()? This may help to clear your intention and will yield better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Join` or `AutoResetEvent` to wait until add picture thread finishes, **But you should not use either as explained later on the answer.**

You can achieve the same results by using `AutoResetEvent` as alternative to `Join`; it allows you to setup a blocking-notification, so block before calling the `execute()` method and only proceed when `AddPics` thread finishes its job:

```
private AutoResetEvent _finishAddPicsNotifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void OnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.....
    new Thread(AddPics)
    {
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest,
        IsBackground = true, //will explain later
    }.Start();

    _finishAddPicsNotifier.WaitOne();//this will block until receive a signal to proceed
    execute();//this method will only be called after the AddPics method finished
    /.....
}

private void AddPics()
{
    try{
        //.......
    }
    finally{
        _finishAddPicsNotifier.Set();//when finished adding the pictures, allow the waiting method to proceed
    }
}
```

**Note:**  Set `IsBackground = true` to indicates that thread is a background thread so it will not prevent the application from terminating. read more about background thread [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx).

**Problems:**

- Since you are using a button click to run the thread, you should add some mechanism to prevent multi-clicks at the same time to run the code multiple time.
- You are also blocking the UI thread when call `Join()` or `_finishAddPicsNotifier.WaitOne()`.

**To fix all of that**, a good design is to define a method `OnFinishAddingPictures` and call it whenever finish adding images, inside this new method call `execute()`, you should also remove the previous `execute()` call from button click:

```
private readonly object _oneAddPicturesLocker = new object();

private void OnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.....
    new Thread(AddPics)
    {
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest,
        IsBackground = true,
    }.Start();
}

private void AddPics()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(_oneAddPicturesLocker))
    {
        //we only can proceed if no other AddPics are running.
        try
        {
            //.....

            OnFinishAddingPictures();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_oneAddPicturesLocker);
        }
    }
}

private void OnFinishAddingPictures()
{
    execute();
}
```

**Note:**

- We get rid of the blocking using this mechanism.
- We are sure One and Only one call to the `AddPics` are executed at a moment.
- Always remember to check `InvokeRequired` and use `control.Invoke(/*..*/)` whenever accessing form or control methods and properties from a thread that **is not the UI thread**.

Comment: @Lokesh: Did you try this approach, does it serves your needs?

Answer (score -3):

I assuming that your primary point is to have responsive UI while the thread with `AddPics` is running? If so, then you can use this construction for WinForms:

```
while (thread.IsAlive)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: Using `Application.DoEvents` is bad idea, it generates  more problems than it solves. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/c-application-doevents/5183623#5183623).

Comment: Calling 'DoEvents()' can cause the problems only in complex application. But if the some person have the head, then 'DoEvents' can serve to good instead evil :)

Comment: It is bad always, because you write it there and forged about it. An example is to have your program and every thing just fine, and after 6 months a new scenario is coming up and you want to get notified whenever computer time changed "for example" you do that by listen to windows messages poll.. you run the application and test it and every thing was just fine.. But wait we forget about the `Application.DoEvents()` that is hidden some where in the code so your application my not be notified if the message received while the `Application.DoEvent()`

Comment: "and after 6 months..." == "complex application"